# Growth Rate $n\ln n$

Tags: logarithms, asymptotics

I mistakenly posted this on MathOverflow. I hope this is a better place for it.

I have been investigating a problem about sports teams and came across the function $n\ln(n)$. I want to see if I can find a connection between my problem and other mathematics through this function. Where else does this function occur? Are there other common situations?

Someone suggested the Coupon Collector Problem. Are there other situations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $p_n$ be the $n$-th prime. The [Prime Number Theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem) tells us that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{p_n}{n\ln n} = 1. $$

Comment: @triple_sec Nope, it is in the denominator. You're probably confusing $p_n$ and $\pi(n)$.

Comment: @DavidColey You're very welcome.

Comment: @triple_sec Were you?

Comment: @VincenzoOliva You are right, I apologize—going to delete the erroneous comment.

Comment: @triple_sec Oh, alright, no worries.

Answer (score 2):

[Efficient sorting of $n$ random numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Comparison_of_algorithms) with an unknown distribution is expected to take a time proportional to $n \log n$.

The [logarithm of $n!$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) is slightly less than $n \log n$